# Refactoring Code in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, refactoring

I have a *pretty* standard problem here that I am a little confused how to make more elegant in the swift tradition of things.

I have a base URL string in my APIClient, a path for different methods to use, and methods might pass in a optional string.

How do I write this such that it is much cleaner? I feel like I am writing swift code but not using any of the new constructs (like guard, let), etc.

```
// call the API
ApiClient.sharedInstance.getUser("56cfffce227a6c2c9b000001", successCompletion: successCompletion, failureCompletion: failureCompletion)

// setting the current URL
let currentURL = String("http://localhost:3000")

// class definition
class ApiClient {

    var baseURL:String!;

    // have to init the string class for the
    init (base:String){
        self.baseURL = base
    }

    class var sharedInstance: ApiClient  {
        struct Static{
            static let instance = ApiClient(base: currentURL)
        }
        return Static.instance
    }


    func getUser(user_id: String?, successCompletion: ResultHandler<User>, failureCompletion:ResultHandler<FailureReason>){

        // this is awkward
        var url: URLStringConvertible!

        // this is even more awkward
        if user_id != nil {
            url = "\(currentURL)/users/\(user_id!).json"
        } else {
            url = "\(currentURL)/users/me"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cleaned some things up and removed some unnecessary forced-unwraps.

```
class ApiClient {

var baseURL: String;

// have to init the string class for the
init (base:String){
    self.baseURL = base
}

class var sharedInstance: ApiClient  {
    struct Static{
        static let instance = ApiClient(base: currentURL)
    }
    return Static.instance
}


func getUser(user_id: String?, successCompletion: ResultHandler<User>, failureCompletion:ResultHandler<FailureReason>){

    var url: URLStringConvertible
    if let user_id = user_id {
        url = "\(currentURL)/users/\(user_id!).json"
    }
    else{
        url = "\(currentURL)/users/me"
    }
```

}

Depending on what you're doing in getUser, things could be done differently.

FYI, what I tend to do for singletons: (arguably not the best):

```
private static var realSharedInstance: Class?
static var sharedInstance: Class {
     get {
         if let realSharedInstance = realSharedInstance {
             return realSharedInstance
         }
         else{
             realSharedInstance = Class()
             return realSharedInstance!
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Even better for creating a singleton is this one liner:     `static let sharedInstance = MyClass()`   http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Comment: The potential issue is you can only set that once, so it's not very versatile.

Comment: thanks! what is the benefit of doing this for singleton?

Comment: Singletons are really useful when you need to access something from multiple classes or from different parts of your application. You often will want this for timers, and you also usually want to keep it running regardless of the state of other objects so it doesn't really make sense for it to belong to other objects.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I like to create an Endpoint for every endpoint that the API supports. In this case, a UsersEndpoint which can make requests via APIClient.
This is easier to scale (for me) when there more endpoints and each endpoint has multiple resources.

Use in code:

```
MyAPI.sharedInstance.users.getUser(id, parameters: params, success: {}, failure: {})
MyAPI.sharedInstance.anotherEndpoint.doSomething(parameters: params, success: {}, failure: {})
```

The classes:

```
class MyAPI {

  static let sharedInstance = MyAPI()

  let users: UsersEndpoint
  // more endpoints here

  init() {
    users = UsersEndpoint()
    // ....
  }

}

class APIClient {

  static let sharedClient = APIClient()
  var manager : Alamofire.Manager!

  var baseURL: String

  init() {
    baseURL = String(format: "https://%@%@", self.instanceUrl, API.Version)
  }

  func get(endpoint endpoint: String,
           parameters: [String:AnyObject],
           success: SuccessCallback,
           failure: FailureCallback) {

    let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "\(self.baseURL)\(endpoint)")!
    manager.request(.GET, requestUrl, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseData { response in

      switch response.result {
      case .Success(let value):
        if let data: NSData = value {
          success(data: data)
          log.verbose("Success - GET requestUrl=\(requestUrl)")
        }
        break;
      case .Failure(let error):
        failure(error: error)
        log.error("Failure - GET requestUrl=\(requestUrl)\nError = \(error.localizedDescription)")
        break;
      }

    }
  }

}

class APIFacade {

  var endpoint: String

  init(endpoint: String) {
    self.endpoint = endpoint;
  }

  func get(endpoint endpoint: String,
           parameters: [String:AnyObject],
           success: SuccessCallback,
           failure: FailureCallback) {
    APIClient.sharedClient.get(endpoint: endpoint, parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
  }

}

class UsersEndpoint: APIFacade {

  init() {
    super.init(endpoint: "/users")
  }

  func getUser(id: String, parameters: [String:AnyObject], success: SuccessCallback, failure: FailureCallback) {
    super.get(endpoint: "\(self.endpoint)/\(id)", parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
  }
}
```